# Find all solutions of $f$ such that $ \operatorname{Cov}(f(x),x)=c $ where $x \sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ and $c$ does not depend on $(\mu,\sigma^2)$

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, covariance

Find all solutions of $f$ such that 
$$ \operatorname{Cov}(f(x),x)=c$$ 
where $x \sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ and $c$ does not depend on $(\mu,\sigma^2)$

I think the only solution is $f$ is constant (almost surely). I am trying to first show that $c=0$, $E[f(x)]=0$ and $E[f(x)x]=0$ and then that $E[f(x)]=0$ implies $f(x)=0$.

I can more or less show that $E[f(x)]=0$ implies $f(x)=0$ by
\begin{align*}
E[f(x)]=(2 \pi \sigma^2)^{-1/2}\int f(x)e^{-(x-\mu)^2/2\sigma^2}dx
\end{align*}
Then changing to complex coordinates and analytic continuity I think this can be viewed as a Fourier transform so if $E[f(x)]=0$ then $f$ is zero.... although this is obviously not rigorous (and not 100\% sure correct).

To show that $c=0$, $E[f(x)]=0$ and $E[f(x)x]=0$, I was thinking of using choices of $(\mu,\sigma^2)$ and Cauchy-Schwarz.

Comment: Sometimes you can get confused by using the same letter, the lower-case $x$, to refer to two different things in the same line, as in $\displaystyle E[f(x)]=(2 \pi \sigma^2)^{-1/2}\int f(x)e^{-(x-\mu)^2/2\sigma^2} \, dx$.  I'd have written $\displaystyle E[f(X)]=(2 \pi \sigma^2)^{-1/2}\int f(x)e^{-(x-\mu)^2/2\sigma^2} \, dx$, with capital $X$ for the random variable and lower-case $x$ for the variable with respect to which one integrates. Without this distinction, an expression like $\Pr(X\le x)$ would be incomprehensible. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the functions under consideration must be integrable (finite $L^1$-norm).  Denote the set of all solutions $f$ by $\mathcal{F}$.  To start, I decided to restrict attention to smooth functions $f \in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$.  For such $f$ it is easy to estimate that off of a $\delta$-ball about $\mu$ such that $\delta/\sigma \to \infty$ as $\sigma \to 0$,
\begin{eqnarray*}
\left|(2\pi\sigma^2)^{-1/2} \int_{B(\mu,\delta)^C}(x-\mu)f(x)e^{-(x-\mu)^2/2\sigma^2} dx \right| & \leq & (2\pi\sigma^2)^{-1/2} \|f\|_{L^1(\mathbb{R})} \sup_{\mathbb{R}\backslash B(\mu,\delta)} |x-\mu|e^{-(x-\mu)^2/2\sigma^2} \\
& \leq & (2\pi)^{-1/2} \|f\|_{L^1(\mathbb{R})}{\delta\over\sigma} e^{-\delta^2/2\sigma^2} \\
& = & \epsilon(\sigma) \to 0.
\end{eqnarray*}
and note that if we take $\delta = \sqrt[3]{\sigma}$ for example, the $\epsilon(\sigma)$ goes to zero faster than any power of $\sigma$.  This leads to 
\begin{eqnarray*}
|\operatorname{Cov}(f(x),x)| & = & (2\pi\sigma^2)^{-1/2} \left|\int_R (x-\mu)f(x) e^{-(x-\mu)^2/2\sigma^2} dx \right| \\
& \leq & (2\pi\sigma^2)^{-1/2} \left| \int_{\mu-\delta}^{\mu+\delta} f(x)(x-\mu)dx \right| + (2\pi)^{-1/2}\|f\|_{L^1(\mathbb{R})}{\delta \over \sigma} e^{-\delta^2/2\sigma^2} \\
 & = & (2\pi\sigma^2)^{-1/2} \left( \max|f| \delta^2 + \epsilon(\sigma) \right) \to 0
\end{eqnarray*}
where $\max |f|$ refers to the largest magnitude of $f$ on $B(\mu,\delta)$. 
 So the constant $c$ must be zero for any $f \in C^{\infty}$.

We estimate the function on the $\delta$-ball about $\mu$ by $f(x) = f(\mu) + f'(\mu)(x-\mu) + h(x)$ where $h(x) = O(|x-\mu|^2)$.  Now we can write
\begin{eqnarray*}
\operatorname{Cov}(f(x),x) &=& (2\pi \sigma^2)^{-1/2} \int_R (x-\mu)f(x)e^{-(x-\mu)^2/2\sigma^2}dx \\
& = & (2\pi)^{-1/2} f'(\mu) \int_{\mu-\delta}^{\mu+\delta} (x-\mu)^2e^{-(x-\mu)^2/2\sigma^2} {dx \over \sigma} \\
&& + (2\pi)^{-1/2}\int_{\mu-\delta}^{\mu+\delta}(x-\mu)h(x) e^{-(x-\mu)^2/2\sigma^2}{dx \over \sigma} + \epsilon(\sigma) \\
& = & (2\pi)^{-1/2} f'(\mu)\sigma^2 \int_{-\delta/\sigma}^{\delta/\sigma} w^2e^{-w^2/2}dw + \text{const}\cdot \sigma^3 + \epsilon(\sigma) \\
& \to & f'(\mu) \sigma^2 + \text{l.o.t.}
\end{eqnarray*}

Now if $f \in \mathcal{F} \cap C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ and $f$ is nonconstant, then for some $a \in \mathbb{R}$ we have $f'(a) \neq 0$.  Taking $\mu = a$ and $\sigma$ small, we find
$$ \operatorname{Cov}(f,x) = \sigma^2 f'(a) + o(\sigma^4), $$
which is nonzero for $\sigma > 0$ small enough.  This contradicts the assumption $f \in \mathcal{F}$, so we conclude that all smooth functions that are in $\mathcal{F}$ must be constant.

By the continuity of the covariance operator $\operatorname{Cov}(\cdot, x)$ we can extend this result from smooth functions to $L^1$ functions.

Note that we need $\sigma \to 0$ to get the first estimate and $\delta \to 0$ to get the linear estimate on $f$.  For the covariance to go to zero with $\sigma$ we also need $\delta^2/\sigma \to 0$.  If we choose $\delta(\sigma) = \sigma^{1/3}$, we can satisfy all these conditions.

Comment: Thanks for the excellent answer. I don't understand why the following is true and why it is even needed "and note that if we take $\delta=\sqrt{\sigma}$, then $\varepsilon(\sigma)$..." Also, I think in the equations following "This leads to" there should be $(2\pi \sigma^2)^{-1/2}$ (i.e. missing $\sigma$).

Comment: You're right about the $\sigma$, I'll edit that.  I need the fact that $\delta/\sigma$ goes to infinity because several of the integrals require a substitution which changes the bounds to $\pm \delta/\sigma$.  If $\delta$ went to zero faster than $\sigma$ these integrals would vanish and we'd lose our estimate.

Comment: I misread - we need $\epsilon(\sigma)$ to go to zero faster than $\sigma^2$ in order to show that $f'(a)\sigma^2$ is the leading term of $Cov(f(x),x)$.  That $\epsilon(\sigma)$ does this follows from $$ \lim_{x\to 0} x^ke^{-x^2} = \lim_{x\to 0} {x^k \over e^{x^2}} = 0$$ for any power $k$ (L'Hospital).

Comment: In the equation following "Now we can write" just wanted to confirm / ask a few things: (1) the expansion is where you use that $f$ is smooth (is smoothness used anywhere else? (2) why do you divide the integral to inside and outside the ball i.e. wouldn't the integral $\int_{\mathbb{R}} (x-\mu)^2e^{-(x-\mu)^2/2\sigma^2} {dx} $ just equal the variance and (3) where does $|x-\mu|^3$ come from?

Comment: Yes, smoothness is just required to use the linear approximation.  The remainder (multiplied by $(x-\mu)$) is of order $(x-\mu)^3$.  This is why I've erroneously included the $|x-\mu|^3$ term.  I'll edit that.  To your second question - the idea was to use a very narrow Gaussian r.v. to act as an approximate identity.

Comment: The Gaussian is not compactly supported though, so I separated the integral into a region containing $\delta/\sigma$ standard deviations, and the rest of the real line.  The integral over $B(\mu,\delta)$ _does_ converge to the variance times $f'(\mu)$, but we have to be inside a small ball in order to expand $f$ - this is why we can't just integrate over $\mathbb{R}$.  If $f$ is not analytic the approximation can fail outside small neighborhoods of $\mu$.

Comment: Could you provide some detail concerning the reduction of the general case ("$L^1$ functions", whatever that might mean) to the case of smooth $f$?

Comment: @JohnDawkins I think this follows because smooth functions are dense in $L^1$ i.e. any function in $L^1$ can be arbitrarily well approximated by smooth functions and as you take the limit of smooth functions you get any function in $L^1$ (also continuity of Cov operator is needed).

Comment: But is it obvious that $L^1$ (for the normal distribution?) solutions can be approximated by smooth solutions?

Comment: @JohnDawkins The assumption is that $f \in L^1$ i.e. $\int f (x)dx < \infty$.... I don't think it's obvious that any function in $L^1$ can be approximated by smooth functions but I'm relatively sure it's true.

Comment: @user103828: Do you find it problematic that none of your smooth solutions (i.e, the constant functions) are in $L^1$?

Comment: @JohnDawkins That's a very good point (sorry didn't understand your question at first).... I think this can still be fixed by (1) the first equation can be made arbitrarily small i.e. $|(2\pi\sigma^2)^{-1/2} \int_{B(\mu,\delta)^C}(x-\mu)f(x)e^{-(x-\mu)^2/2\sigma^2} dx |$ can be made arbitrarily small by letting any number of standard deviations be inside the ball. This then shows that $cov(f(x),x)=0$ and (2) assuming that smooth functions are dense in the set of functions considered (I think smooth functions are dense in a lot of spaces).... but Titus should confirm all this.

Comment: Well, the question doesn't specify a function space to work with.  All we know is that $E[f(x)]$ should exist (that is, $f$ is integrable against an arbitrary normal) and $E[xf(x)]$ should exist.  These conditions are not the same as $f$ being in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$, but if it is then they're both satisfied.  The $L^1$ space is very common so that's what I used.  Again, it may not be the most general setting that the question may be answered, but if you were interested in other functions the same proof could likely be used with slight adjustment.

Comment: Another good reason to use $L^1$ functions is that it is well-known that $C^{\infty}_0$ is dense in that function space.  You should be able to find a proof in any real analysis text (I think I saw this in F. Jones' "Lebesgue Integration on Euclidean Space.")  I'm sure you could find  a proof here as well; I think the proof uses a convolution with a smooth approximate identity.

Comment: @Titus: But, as noted already, there are no $L^1$ solutions.

Comment: i.e. is it a problem that $f(x)=c \not \in L^1$ i.e. $\int f(x)dx=\int c dx$ is infinite? ... I think maybe the solution still holds by looking at functions where the measure is the normal distribution (smooth solutions are dense in this space).

Comment: @JohnDawkins Yes, noted.  Actually, the zero function is in the solution space and $L^1(\mathbb{R})$, but what OP wrote above is correct - we could consider the intersection (over all normal distributions) of functions with finite covariance with the normal.  Then we can still show that $c=0$, but we lose our next estimate.  So perhaps we can restrict to bounded functions and everyone will be happy.

Comment: I didn't focus on the obvious constant solutions here, since my main concern when I heard the problem was "How can we approach this when $f$ can be discontinuous?"  Approximating with a smooth integrable function was one obvious fix.  I think it is good to start by getting any solution down, then try relaxing your assumptions if possible.